# Multisite support for ActionMailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer

There exists the multisite plugin (http://github.com/dasil003/rails-multisite/tree/master) that allows for multiple view folders based on different sites. It especially allows you to only overwrite certain views in a site and leave the others untouched (i.e. the other views don't exist twice).

Does something like this exist for ActionMailer, too? Setting `ActionMailer::Base.template_root` isn't enough as this has to be a string and doesn't allow an array (as `ActionController::Base.view_paths` does).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did it myself: [multisite_action_mailer](http://github.com/msales/multisite_action_mailer/tree/master)